# Why need to set signed.applets.codebase_principal_support to true

Tags: browser, applet

I'm on a web page and selected a few words. When hitting 'control-C' or select 'copy' from the context menu, it pops up a dialog saying: your browser has refused the operation, open about:config and set signed.applets.codebase_principal_support to true.

What is this flag and its effect? Why it needs to be set to true? Why doing the same on other pages does not trigger this problem?

The browser is a firefox on its latest version.

Comment: I still see this once in a longer while like a few months.

Comment: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ prompts me to set it when hitting the paste button.